# Exposing resetting active directory password function to third party application

Tags: active-directory, reset-password

I currently have a Windows server in which I uses Active Directory to manage my user's account. I want to expose my password reset script functionality to a third party application. How can I achieve this with most optimal security?

Currently, I have written a PowerShell script to automate the password reset. I planned to allow PowerShell remote to allow the third party application to execute my script. But I am not sure how to constrain the third party to only be able to execute the script via the script and if this is the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at constrained PowerShell endpoints. You can create a "session configuration" that will restrict what can be done, then also restrict who can connect using that configuration.

I can't walk you through how to do it because I've never done it, but there is a whole series of articles on it here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/introduction-to-powershell-endpoints/